# MFC editable combobox selects text on its own. Don't want this

Tags: mfc, combobox

I tested this in one of my sandbox MFC apps and confirmed this result.

If an item is selected in an editable combobox, the next time the combobox recieves a windowsposchanging message, it sends out a select text windows message which selects all the text.

Getting and selecting window text from edit in an editable combobox is unreliable, so we instead add an item and select it to change the combobox's text, which reacts the same way as the user selecting an item. Next time everything is recalculated on a move, SetWindowPos causes the edit text to be selected.

Overriding WindowPosChanging message has weird results, because combobox actually ignores setting it's height. What it does with the height value is subtract what it calculates its height should be (based on font size), and uses the remainder for the dropdown listbox's height. Why there isn't a set dropdown height method is beyond me.

So the only thing I can think of is have a member flag that overrides the seltext message and does nothing if the flag is set, but that's a horrible solution.

Any advice on how to prevent the text selection?

Comment: What exactly do you want? You want to subclass a combobox?

Comment: I've already tried subclassing combobox. Doesn't work. I can't intercept the setsel message that's sent. It just happens after I receive a setwindowpos message. No documentation on how or why this occurs.

Comment: May be a screen shot may help us to help you

Comment: What's wrong with selecting all the text? That's the way it's supposed to work, and defying Microsoft's plans are usually more trouble than they're worth. That said have a look at `GetComboBoxInfo` to get the HWND of the edit control.

Comment: @Mark Ransom That would be fine, except that the text is selected whenever the window is MOVED, at all. And only if the last thing the user did was select an item from the dropdown list. To make matters worse, it does this to EVERY combobox's edit, including those not in focus. Have you seen an edit suddenly have text selected on a window in the background that you have touched in hours. Is that desirable?

Comment: "Why there isn't a set dropdown height method is beyond me." It is done in the resource editor, by clicking the dropdown arrow and then setting its height by mouse dragging the bottom of selection rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do.  You need to subclass the Edit box owned by the combo box, not the combo box itself.  As Mark said, you can get this by calling GetComboBoxInfo and using the hwndItem field.  Then you can intercept EM_SETSEL.